# In what order should I watch Flash and Arrow TV Shows?

Tags: dc, suggested-order, arrowverse, the-flash-2014, arrow

The two TV shows [Arrow](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2193021/) and [The Flash](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3107288/?ref_=nv_sr_1) cross over (or so I'm told).

I've only been watching Arrow so far, and Barry Allen has [just turned up](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3229412/?ref_=ttep_ep8). Do I need to start watching Flash episodes?

What order do I need watch these shows in?

Comment: Excellent question - I was starting to wonder the same thing :-)

Comment: For a more inclusive answer, (covering the other four interconnected shows as well), see http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117192/what-is-the-viewing-order-for-cws-dc-shared-universe

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Ideally**, you should watch them in the order they aired. That is, if you want to get the most coherent story from both shows, you should watch *Arrow* up through the end of Season 2, then watch alternate episodes of *The Flash* Season 1 and *Arrow* Season 3. There is only one time when the shows seem to be significantly out of sync, and it won't make a whole ton of difference. In particular, watching in this order is the easiest way to guarantee not to spoil anything from either show by watching the other.

The second season of *Arrow* contains what is essentially a two-part pilot episode for *The Flash*, where a mundane Barry Allen comes to Starling City as a forensics expert; the end of that *Arrow* episode sets up the first episode of *The Flash*.

The first episodes of *The Flash* Season 1, and *Arrow* Season 3, take place at the same time, and there are cross-over cameos at the end of those episodes. Otherwise, the crossover events all seem to fall roughly in line with the order the episodes aired (e.g. crossovers that start on *The Flash* finish the next night on *Arrow*, or take place roughly between the previous and next episodes of the other show.)

So, watching in date-aired order is (almost) always going to work best for getting the entire story exactly as it was intended.

---

**However**, if watching them in air-date order is **difficult** (e.g. you're watching on Netflix or DVD where jumping between shows is tedious) you don't *need* to watch the episodes interleaved get the full story. In fact, there is at least once case where that will be a bit confusing:  the timelines of the two series remain mostly in sync with each other for the first 2/3 or the season, but sometime between episodes 9 and 15, *Arrow* pulls ahead of *Flash*. If you're interested, there's a very spoilery explanation here:

[In between which episodes of Arrow did this episode of Flash happen?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86779/in-between-which-episodes-of-arrow-did-this-episode-of-flash-happen)

So, if you prefer watching one show at a time, you really only need to pay attention to the places where the stories meet. I've put together a quick comparison of the timelines of the shows and where they cross. For the episodes in between the cross-over points, you can watch each series straight through if you want. You will miss out on a bit of Easter-Egg-level details, where the shows occasionally refer to each other's ongoing plots, but nothing central ot particularly spoilery (that I know of.)

However, you'll want to make sure you're caught up on both shows at the cross-over points,  or you'll not only be confused, but probably spoil something for yourself in the process. For example, characters from *Arrow* reveal key aspects of *Arrows*'s season 4 plot up to that point when they show up on Season 1 of *Flash*.

```
Flash       Arrow    Crossover
~~~~~       ~~~~~    ~~~~~~~~~

S01E01 <--> S03E01   Same scene appears at the end of both episodes.
   .           .
   .           .
   .           .
S01E04 <--     .     Felicity Smoak visits Barry at some indeterminate point
   .           .
   .           .
   .           .
S01E08 <--     .     Two-part crossover, starts on *Flash*, end on *Arrow*
   .    --> S03E08
   .           .
   .           .
   .        S03E15
S01E18 <--     .     Crossover on *Flash* between episodes 15/16 of *Arrow*
   .        S03E16
S01E19 <--     .     Crossover on *Flash* between episodes 16/17 of *Arrow*
   .        S03E17
   .           .
   .   <--  S03E19   Crossover on *Arrow* between episodes 20/21 of *Flash*
   .           .
   .           .
   .           .     
S01E22 <--> S03E23   *Arrow* episode 23 appears to take place "during" *Flash* episode 22.


S02E01      S04E01
  .           .
  .           .
  .           .
S02E08 <--    .      Two-part crossover, begins on *Flash*, ends
  .     --> S04E08   next day on *Arrow*; also counts as back-door
  .           .      pilot for *Legends of Tomorrow*.

NOTE: The arrows indicate the "direction" of characters crossing from one show to the other
Which is usually character from *Arrow* going to *The Flash*.
```

Comment: I don't understand your last comment; how is *'you could just as easily watch the first 7 episodes of The Flash, then the first 7 episodes of Arrow; then watch the next episode of each; then go back to watching one show at a time.'* and *' if you want to get the most coherent story from both shows, you should watch Arrow up through the end of Season 2, then watch alternate episodes of The Flash Season 1 and Arrow Season 3.'* not mutually exclusive?

Comment: they are mutually exclusive. they are two options, one of which IMO gets you a more coherent story (since there will be occasional throw-away lines referencing each other), but the other will be far more convenient (if, e.g. you're binge-watching one series or the other) at the cost of a tiny bit of continuity.

Comment: Oh, so the 'watch alternatly' is merely for when the characters off-handedly say 'Did you hear about what happened in Central/Starling City...?'

Comment: mostly. Even when I watch several episodes on DVR in a row I alternate, just in case :) but in hindsight you won't miss out on anything "major". Up through ~episode 16ish, the timelines seem to be in sync, and watching them that way just "feels" better to me.

Comment: "Watching the episodes in air order" broke down over the last few weeks - IIRC the last crossover had pretty big things going down in Arrow that were just ignored in Flash. Not that there's a *better* order to watch them in, just that it doesn't always work.

Comment: actually, I'm changing the second 1/2 of my answer to be more detailed, so I can expand on the weird second crossover a bit better.

Answer (score 11):

this question 'Arrows'ed my curiosity. Copy into notepad, save as CSV, import into Excel. You'll have a watch order list in a Flash... sorry.

Show, Series NO., Episode Name, Original Airdate

Arrow, 1, Pilot, October 10 2012

Arrow, 2, Honor Thy Father, October 17 2012

Arrow, 3, Lone Gunmen, October 24 2012

Arrow, 4, An Innocent Man, October 31 2012

Arrow, 5, Damaged, November 7 2012

Arrow, 6, Legacies, November 14 2012

Arrow, 7, Muse of Fire, November 28 2012

Arrow, 8, Vendetta, December 5 2012

Arrow, 9, Year's End, December 12 2012

Arrow, 10, Burned, January 16 2013

Arrow, 11, Trust but Verify, January 23 2013

Arrow, 12, Vertigo, January 30 2013

Arrow, 13, Betrayal, February 6 2013

Arrow, 14, The Odyssey, February 13 2013

Arrow, 15, Dodger, February 20 2013

Arrow, 16, Dead to Rights, February 27 2013

Arrow, 17, The Huntress Returns, March 20 2013

Arrow, 18, Salvation, March 27 2013

Arrow, 19, Unfinished Business, April 3 2013

Arrow, 20, Home Invasion, April 24 2013

Arrow, 21, The Undertaking, May 1 2013

Arrow, 22, Darkness on the Edge of Town, May 8 2013

Arrow, 23, Sacrifice, May 15 2013

Arrow, 24, City of Heroes, October 9 2013

Arrow, 25, Identity, October 16 2013

Arrow, 26, Broken Dolls, October 23 2013

Arrow, 27, Crucible, October 30 2013

Arrow, 28, League of Assassins, November 6 2013

Arrow, 29, Keep Your Enemies Closer, November 13 2013

Arrow, 30, State v. Queen, November 20 2013

Arrow, 31, The Scientist, December 4 2013

Arrow, 32, Three Ghosts, December 11 2013

Arrow, 33, Blast Radius, January 15 2014

Arrow, 34, Blind Spot, January 22 2014

Arrow, 35, Tremors, January 29 2014

Arrow, 36, Heir to the Demon, February 5 2014

Arrow, 37, Time of Death, Febuary 26 2014

Arrow, 38, The Promise, March 5 2014

Arrow, 39, Suicide Squad, March 19 2014

Arrow, 40, Birds of Prey, March 26 2014

Arrow, 41, Deathstroke, April 2 2014

Arrow, 42, The Man Under the Hood, April 16 2014

Arrow, 43, Seeing Red, April 23 2014

Arrow, 44, City of Blood, April 30 2014

Arrow, 45, Streets of Fire, May 7 2014

Arrow, 46, Unthinkable, May 14 2014

Flash, 1, Pilot, October 7 2014

Arrow, 47, The Calm, October 8 2014

Flash, 2, Fastest Man Alive, October 14 2014

Arrow, 48, Sara, October 15 2014

Flash, 3, Things You Can't Outrun, October 21 2014

Arrow, 49, Corto Maltese, October 22 2014

Flash, 4, Going Rogue, October 28 2014

Arrow, 50, The Magician, October 29 2014

Arrow, 51, The Secret Origin of Felicity Smoak, November 5 2014

Flash, 5, Plastique, November 11 2014

Arrow, 52, Guilty, November 12 2014

Flash, 6, The Flash Is Born, November 18 2014

Arrow, 53, Draw Back Your Bow, November 19 2014

Flash, 7, Power Outage, November 25 2014

Flash, 8, Flash vs. Arrow, December 2 2014

Arrow, 54, The Brave and the Bold, December 3 2014

Flash, 9, The Man in the Yellow Suit, December 9 2014

Arrow, 55, The Climb, December 10 2014

Flash, 10, Revenge of the Rogues, January 20 2015

Arrow, 56, Left Behind, January 21 2015

Flash, 11, The Sound and the Fury, January 27 2015

Arrow, 57, Midnight City, January 28 2015

Flash, 12, Crazy for You, February 3 2015

Arrow, 58, Uprising, February 4 2015

Flash, 13, The Nuclear Man, February 10 2015

Arrow, 59, Canaries, February 11 2015

Flash, 14, Fallout, February 17 2015

Arrow, 60, The Return, February 18 2015

Arrow, 61, Nanda Parbat, February 25 2015

Flash, 15, Out of Time, March 17 2015

Arrow, 62, The Offer, March 18 2015

Flash, 16, Rogue Time, March 24 2015

Arrow, 63, Suicidal Tendencies, March 25 2015

Flash, 17, Tricksters, March 31 2015

Arrow, 64, Public Enemy, April 1 2015

Flash, 18, All Star Team Up, April 14 2015

Arrow, 65, Broken Arrow, April 15 2015

Flash, 19, Who is Harrison Wells?, April 21 2015

Arrow, 66, The Fallen, April 22 2015

Flash, 20, The Trap, April 28 2015

Arrow, 67, Al Sah-him, April 29 2015

Flash, 21, Grodd Lives, May 5 2015

Arrow, 68, This Is Your Sword, May 6 2015

Flash, 22, Rogue Air, May 12 2015

Arrow, 69, My Name Is Oliver Queen, May 13 2015

Flash, 23, Fast Enough, May 19 2015

Comment: I've taken the liberty to put that up onto Google Sheets - the URL is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z7IGBAan2O00p36SG5PHOuX-L5TxbyloT1n7ZG5Nnao/edit?usp=sharing for anyone not wanting to fiddle with copy & paste.

Comment: That Google Sheet of mine, thanks to other contributors, now also includes the watch order for Vixen and Legends of Tomorrow.

Comment: You don't explain why you recommend this order. At first glance, it seems to be the order in which they aired, but I don't have the patience to check all of them. I think this would be a better answer if you say explicitly why you picked this order and why you recommend it.

Answer (score 4):

A more simplified list based on **[Rob D's post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/89247/6365)** and **[kguest's comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89097/in-what-order-should-i-watch-flash-and-arrow-tv-shows#comment201276_89247)** post with what I believe to be the correct order to watch based on information from the answers. My main fix up was removing some episodes, since it had all of the first and second season of Arrow which are not exactly needed.

I also made it a little bit easier to read in [this Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DLJYghRtiWrU-yaK2h9PRE1P9CdG87k0rSvDfGqYHAQ/edit?usp=sharing). I did it for myself so I thought why not share it in case other people found the other posts too hard to read like myself.

**The Flash**, S01E01 — Pilot
*Arrow*, S03E01 — The Calm
**The Flash**, S01E02 — Fastest Man Alive
*Arrow*, S03E02 — Sara
**The Flash**, S01E03— Things You Can't Outrun
*Arrow*, S03E03 — Corto Maltese
**The Flash**, S01E04 — Going Rogue
*Arrow*, S03E04 — The Magician
*Arrow*, S03E05 — The Secret Origin of Felicity Smoak
**The Flash**, S01E05 — Plastique
*Arrow*,    S03E060 — Guilty
**The Flash**, S01E06 — The Flash Is Born
*Arrow*, S03E07 — Draw Back Your Bow
**The Flash**, S01E07 — Power Outage
**The Flash**, S01E08 — Flash vs. Arrow
*Arrow*, S03E08 — The Brave and the Bold
**The Flash**, S01E09 — The Man in the Yellow Suit
*Arrow*, S03E09 — The Climb
**The Flash**, S01E10 — Revenge of the Rogues
*Arrow*, S03E10 — Left Behind
**The Flash**, S01E11 — The Sound and the Fury
*Arrow*, S03E11 — Midnight City
**The Flash**, S01E12 — Crazy for You
*Arrow*, S03E12 — Uprising
**The Flash**, S01E13 — The Nuclear Man
*Arrow*, S03E13 — Canaries
**The Flash**, S01E14 — Fallout
**The Flash**, S01E15 — Out of Time
**The Flash**, S01E16 — Rogue Time
**The Flash**, S01E17 — Tricksters
*Arrow*, S03E14 — The Return
*Arrow*, S03E15 — Nanda Parbat
*Arrow*, S03E16 — The Offer
**The Flash**, S01E18 — All Star Team Up
**The Flash**, S01E19 — Who is Harrison Wells?
*Arrow*, S03E17 — Suicidal Tendencies
*Arrow*, S03E18 — Public Enemy
*Arrow*, S03E19 — Broken Arrow
*Arrow*, S03E20 — The Fallen
**The Flash**, S01E20 — The Trap
*Arrow*, S03E21 — Al Sah-him
**The Flash**, S01E21 — Grodd Lives
*Arrow*, S03E22 — This Is Your Sword
**The Flash**, S01E22 — Rogue Air
*Arrow* S03E23 — My Name Is Oliver Queen
**The Flash**, S01E23 — Fast Enough

**UPDATED TO INCLUDE Arrow S4 and Flash S2 Air Dates**

**The Flash**, S201 - The Man Who Saved Central City (Air Date: 6-Oct-15)
*The Arrow*, S401 - Green Arrow (Air Date: 7-Oct-15)
**The Flash**, S202 - Flash of Two Worlds (Air Date: 13-Oct-1)
*The Arrow*, S402 - The Candidate (Air Date: 14-Oct-15)
**The Flash**, S203 - Family of Rogues (Air Date: 20-Oct-15)
*The Arrow*, S403 - Restoration (Air Date: 21-Oct-15)
**The Flash**, S204 - The Fury of Firestorm (Air Date: 27-Oct-15)
*The Arrow*, S404 - Beyond Redemption (Air Date: 28-Oct-15)
**The Flash**, S205 - The Darkness and the Light (Air Date: 3-Nov-15)
*The Arrow*, S405 - Haunted (Air Date: 4-Nov-15)
**The Flash**, S206 - Enter Zoom (Air Date: 10-Nov-15)
*The Arrow*, S406 - Lost Souls (Air Date: 11-Nov-15)
**The Flash**, S207 - Gorilla Warfare (Air Date: 17-Nov-15)
*The Arrow*, S407 - Brotherhood (Air Date: 18-Nov-15)
**The Flash**, S208 - Legends of Today (Air Date: 1-Dec-15)
*The Arrow*, S408 - Legends of Yesterday (Air Date: 2-Dec-15)
**The Flash**, S209 - Running to Stand Still (Air Date: 8-Dec-15)
*The Arrow*, S409 - Dark Waters (Air Date: 9-Dec-15)
**The Flash**, S210 - Potential Energy (Air Date: 19-Jan-16)
*The Arrow*, S410 - Blood Debts (Air Date: 20-Jan-16)
**The Flash**, S211 - The Reverse Flash Returns (Air Date: 26-Jan-16)
*The Arrow*, S411 - A.W.O.L. (Air Date: 27-Jan-16)
**The Flash**, S212 - Fast Lane (Air Date: 2-Feb-16)
*The Arrow*, S412 - Unchained (Air Date: 3-Feb-16)
**The Flash**, S213 - Welcome to Earth-2 (Air Date: 9-Feb-16)
*The Arrow*, S413 - Sins of the Father (Air Date: 10-Feb-16)
**The Flash**, S214 - Escape from Earth-2 (Air Date: 16-Feb-16)
*The Arrow*, S414 - Code of Silence (Air Date: 17-Feb-16)
**The Flash**, S215 - King Shark (Air Date: 23-Feb-16)
*The Arrow*, S415 - Taken (Air Date: 24-Feb-16)
**The Flash**, S216 - Trajectory (Air Date: 22-Mar-16)
*The Arrow*, S416 - Broken Hearts (Air Date: 23-Mar-16)
**The Flash**, S217 - Flash Back (Air Date: 29-Mar-16)
*The Arrow*, S417 - Beacon of Hope (Air Date: 30-Mar-16)
*The Arrow*, S418 - Eleven-Fifty-Nine (Air Date: 6-Apr-16)
**The Flash**, S218 - Versus Zoom (Air Date: 19-Apr-16)
**The Flash**, S219 - Back to Normal (Air Date: 26-Apr-16)
*The Arrow*, S419 - Canary Cry (Air Date: 27-Apr-16)
**The Flash**, S220 - Rupture (Air Date: 3-May-16)
*The Arrow*, S420 - Genesis (Air Date: 4-May-16)
**The Flash**, S221 - The Runaway Dinosaur (Air Date: 10-May-16)
*The Arrow*, S421 - Monument Point (Air Date: 11-May-16)
**The Flash**, S222 - Invincible (Air Date: 17-May-16)
*The Arrow*, S422 - Lost in the Flood (Air Date: 18-May-16)
**The Flash**, S223 - The Race of His Life (Air Date: 24-May-16)
*The Arrow*, S423 - Schism (Air Date: 25-May-16)

Comment: Flash 1x22 - Rogue Air has Ollie asking Barry for a favour in return that Barry fulfills in Arrow 3x23, but your order doesn't reflect that.

Comment: The end of Arrow, S419, where Barry appears, does not fit the "state" in which Barry is in Flash, S219.