# Can I start Arrow from season 3 if I've seen Flash?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014, arrow

So can I just start Arrow on season 3 episode 1?  I haven't watched Arrow yet but I've watched the first 4 episodes of Flash.

Comment: Welcome to the site. It seems you've asked a duplicate question about watching the Flash and Arrow TV series. Fear not that your question is a duplicate. If anything it means it's a good question. Your question will help others who may have a similar search query to you find that other answer. If you have any other questions, feel free to press that [Ask Question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button again!

Comment: You may also find [What is the viewing order for CW's DC shared universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/117192/70236) useful.

Comment: Possibly a better dupe: [Do I need to watch Arrow before I watch The Flash?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/92159/5184)

Comment: not exactly the same question but I think close enough.

Comment: I imagine it will make as little sense in all cases, regardless of where you start watching from.